# Implementing Neville's Algorithm in MatLab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, interpolation

I'm attempting to implement Neville's algorithm in MatLab with four given points in this case. However, I'm a little stuck at the moment. 
This is my script so far:

```
% Neville's Method

% Function parameters
x = [7,14,21,28];
fx = [58,50,54,53];
t = 10;

n = length(x);
Q = zeros(n,n);


for i = 1:n
    Q(i,1) = fx(i);
end
for j = 2:n
    for i = j:n
        Q(i,j) = ((t-x(i-j)) * Q(i,j-1)/(x(i)-x(i-j))) + ((x(i)-t) * Q(i-1,j-1)/(x(i)-x(i-j)));
    end
end

print(Q);
```

As for the problem I'm having, I'm getting this output consistently:
**Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.**

I've been trying to tweak the loop iterations but to no avail. I know the problem is the primary logic line in the inner loop. Some of the operations result in array indices that are equal to zero initially.

That's where I am, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop at the first time `i-j` is `0` because you set `i = j`. In MATLAB indices start at `1`. A simple fix to get running code would be to change

```
for i = j:n
```

to

```
for i = j+1:n
```

This solves

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

However, this may not be ideal and you may need to rethink your logic. The output I get is

```
>> neville
Q =

   58.0000         0         0         0
   50.0000         0         0         0
   54.0000   50.8571         0         0
   53.0000   54.2857   51.3469         0
```